# How to get only the datatypes of df in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

Using `df.dtypes` on my df gives me:

```
AccountKey                         int64
ParentAccountKey                 float64
AccountCodeAlternateKey            int64
```

I only need the datatypes, and not the column names. How to get this?

I want to achieve something like this :

```
 if datatypes contain 'varchar':
       flag = 1
```

Comment: is this what you want `df.dtypes.to_numpy()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of `df.dtpyes` is a Series, just extract the values part.

```
df.dtypes.values
```

For the thing you want to achieve :

```
flag = [1 if x == "O" else 0 for x in df.dtypes.values ]
```